# How to create exe for C# windows form application

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, installation, exe

I have developed an application using C# and Windows Forms, and there are some reports for which I used Crystal Reports. I want to know how to create an `.exe` file for my application with Crystal Reports run time. Thank you.

Comment: you can lookout for exe file in your project directory's bin folder.for example D:\yourproject\bin\.

Answer (score 2):

.exe file of the application is in the bin folder of the application.